# Does graphics card resolution apply to both outputs?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution

I have a graphics card with Maximum Digital Resolution at 2560x1600. It's the GeForce GTS 250.

It has 2 DVI outputs.

Will it support 2 monitors at 2560x1600 as well as it would support 1?

Specs:
http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gts250/specifications

Comment: No, it would require more processing power to run two displays over one. That being said it will be depended upon the tasks you perform as to if you would see anything noticeable to the eye.

Comment: The video card will physical support 2 monitors, YES.  However email, web surfing, and other low powered work the effect would be very small.  "FarCry 3" and other 3d work the frame rate will drop so low it will be unplayable.

Comment: @cybernard so maybe disconnect one monitor when playing games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Maximum Digital Resolution" listed in most of the video card specs, is indicating the Max possible PER output.  Cards with multiple outputs can run multiple monitors. The ability of them to run multiples at the "Max" would be if they support the 2 outputs which this one does.

EX: my video card has a maximum resolution that is far smaller than the 2 X 1920 monitors that it runs on seperate outputs. The card does not say the max is 3840. (until referring to eyefinitys max)

Comment: That makes sense. I am doing a bit of "eyefinity" and certainly the total resolution is more than 2560x1600. Thanks for the confirmation.